# Using hydra from CI

Tags: ruby, continuous-integration, hudson

I am trying to convert my test suite to use [hydra](https://github.com/ngauthier/hydra)

It is working nicely when I run it from command line, but I now want to integrate it into my build process. To do this I need some nice output.

Are there any formatters available to make hydra output work with hudson? Or just generally to make an html file (much like cucumber gives you natively)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out that you can use the junit formatter to get output that can be read by hudson. This works even when using hydra as it puts output for each feature file in its own xml file.

To get html output to work I had to do a little more work. I forked hydra, wrote a cucumber formatter to output html on a per file basis and then added a listener to hydra to stitch them together at the end.

You can find the fork [here](https://github.com/dereke/hydra) I am hoping to get it pulled into hydra soon.